# Kids that build some sort of space craft

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

This movie was about a bunch of kids that were building a type of space ship and they built something that projected a bubble around their craft and this bubble allowed them to travel great distances fast etc.

I remember one scene, they fired (accidental or not I cannot remember) this bubble in the ground and it made a huge hole into the earth, which seemed to go on forever. I vaguely remember one of the kids remarked "its probably half way to china now", but I could have mistaken this quote.

It sounds a lot like an 1980's science fiction movie, but as to the cast and other plots I cannot remember.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but it sounds like you're referring to [Explorers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089114/).  This was an 80's movie that featured a ship built by kids, surrounded by a bubble.

I don't remember the hole in the earth scene, but it sounds like something that would have been in this movie, and perhaps I just don't remember it.